# What are your favorite usability research mailing lists?

Tags: resources, research, email

I'm a researcher at university and my focus is mainly on usability issues of certain software solutions, for example in the field of IT-security, user authentication, and privacy enhancing technologies. I do mostly empirical studies involving user testing. What mailing lists (or ohter web ressources that focus on recent developments in the fiels) could you recommend, that focus more on this more scientific part of our profession?

Comment: I guess that you're already a member of ACM and IEEE?

Comment: I myself am not. Our university, on the other hand, is of course subscribed to the ACM and IEEE publications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SIGCHI](http://www.sigchi.org/) (ACM) is quite prominent and frequented by academics.

[IxDA](http://www.ixda.org/), while being definitely more on the practical side, also has the occasional academic question on its mailing list.

Comment: Is it possible to subscribe to all of CHI lists by receiving a digest?  Or do I have to do each individually and get a ton of different e-mails?